# mutate or filter according to conditions from tibble

Tags: r, left-join, dplyr

I'm currently working through [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz), and specifically working on exercise [5.7.1 #8](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#exercises-12) which is analyzing the `library(nycflights13)` package data.

The question reads:

> 8. For each plane, count the number of flights before the first delay of greater than 1 hour.

My attempt was to create a table that finds the first "over 60 minute" delay by using the `first()` function:

```
first_del <- flights %>%
  select(month, day, flight, dep_time, tailnum, dep_delay) %>%
  filter(dep_delay > 60) %>%
  group_by(month,day) %>%
  arrange(month, day, dep_time) %>%
  summarise(flight = first(flight), first_time = first(dep_time))

first_del

# A tibble: 365 x 4
# Groups:   month [?]
    month   day flight first_time
    <int> <int>  <int>      <int>
 1     1     1   4576        811
 2     1     2     22        126
 3     1     3    104         50
 4     1     4    608        106
 5     1     5     11         37
 6     1     6     27        746
 7     1     7    145        756
 8     1     8   4334        740
 9     1     9     51        641
10     1    10    905        743
# ... with 355 more rows
```

My idea is to tag each row in the `flights` tibble 1 if if it matches the month, day, and is less than the flight number of the first delayed flight on that day (for example, from the `first_del` tibble above, flight 4576 is the first "over 60 minute delayed" flight on Jan 1, and every other flight before it will count). The desired output would be something like:

```
  flights %>%
  filter(dep_time > 805) %>%
  select(month, day, flight, dep_time, tag)

# A tibble: 272,933 x 4
   month   day flight dep_time   tag
   <int> <int>  <int>    <int>  <int>
 1     1     1    269      807    1
 2     1     1   4388      809    1
 3     1     1   3538      810    1
 4     1     1   2395      810    1
 5     1     1   4260      811    1
 6     1     1   4576      811    1
 7     1     1    675      811    0
 8     1     1   4537      812    0
 9     1     1    914      813    0
10     1     1    346      814    0
```

Ideally, it would be great to tally all rows less than or equal to the flight number on each day according to the `first_del` tibble. I've tried to use many combinations of filter, %in%, mutate, but have not yet been successful. Should I create a custom function?

My ultimate desired output is (with **fictitious** `$count` values):

```
 first_del

# A tibble: 365 x 4
# Groups:   month [?]
    month   day flight first_time  count
    <int> <int>  <int>      <int>  <int>
 1     1     1   4576        811    212
 2     1     2     22        126    216
 3     1     3    104         50    298
 4     1     4    608        106    220
 5     1     5     11         37    168
 6     1     6     27        746    287
 7     1     7    145        756    302
 8     1     8   4334        740    246
 9     1     9     51        641    235
10     1    10    905        743    313
```

where `$count` is the number of flights that preceded the first delayed flight on that day (as wanted by the question in the links above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which.max` on a logical vector to determine the first instance satisfying a condition. You also need to check the condition actually occurs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

flights %>%
  mutate(dep_delay = coalesce(dep_delay, 0)) %>%
  arrange(month, day, dep_time) %>%
  group_by(tailnum) %>%
  summarise(max_delay = max(dep_delay), 
            which_first_geq_1hr = which.max(dep_delay > 60)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(max_delay > 60)
```

I'm assuming that delay means departure delay, `NA` delay means `0` or at least less than an hour, and I'm ignoring planes that 'failed' to be delayed by more than hour. The `coalesce` is necessary to avoid `which.max(NA)`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is per plane, so you really want to operate grouped by `tailnum`. You can add a flag column, but really you need to end up with something you can pass to `filter` (a logical vector) or `slice` (a vector of row indices). There are various ways to do this, e.g. `slice(seq(c(which(dep_delay > 60) - 1, n())[1]))`, but a nice approach is to use dplyr's `cumall` (a cumulative version of `all`, like `cumsum` is to `sum`) to generate a logical vector for `filter`:

```r
library(dplyr)

nycflights13::flights %>% 
    group_by(tailnum) %>% 
    arrange(year, month, day, dep_time) %>%    # ensure order before cumany
    filter(cumall(pmax(dep_delay, arr_delay) < 60)) %>% 
    tally()    # count number of observations per group (tailnum)
#> # A tibble: 3,709 x 2
#> # Groups:   tailnum [3,709]
#>    tailnum     n
#>    <chr>   <int>
#>  1 N10156      9
#>  2 N102UW     25
#>  3 N103US     46
#>  4 N104UW      3
#>  5 N105UW     22
#>  6 N107US     20
#>  7 N108UW     36
#>  8 N109UW     28
#>  9 N110UW     15
#> 10 N11107      7
#> # ... with 3,699 more rows
```

It's possible to make a intermediate table of first big delays and do a self-join to ID where they are, or add a flag value to some observations with `if_else`, but regardless, subsetting up to those rows will still require similar logic to the `cumall` above, so they're really just longer, slower approaches.